# Immutable data on a trait

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to define a trait with a method returning some data, but this data must not be changed by the `impl`, i.e. it can only be set once and remain in that value for the lifetime of the `impl`. Is there any way to ensure this?

Here's how I would accomplish this in C#, for reference:

```
public abstract class Foo 
{
    private readonly uint number;

    public Foo(uint number) { this.number = numbers; }

    public uint GetNumber() { return number; }

}
```

Comment: I don't have a complete answer for you so I'm just going to leave a comment. 1) The closer analogy for a trait in C# would be an interface. How would you approach solving this with an interface? 2) Can you explain at a higher level what problem you're trying to solve? Why do implementations of the trait need to hold a piece of immutable data? Why does it need to be immutable?

Comment: Looks like XY problem. What exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **no**. There is no way to accomplish this in a way analogous to the C# approach. Fortunately, Rust provides better control over mutability than C#.

Understanding how immutability works in Rust and how it differs from languages like C# and Java is important.

**Immutability in C#**

```cs
class Foo {
   readonly Bar bar = new Bar();
   uint lives;
}
```

Some things to note:

- Immutability is defined per-field.
- Immutability is shallow. For example, even though the reference to `bar` is immutable, the values that `bar` refers to are still mutable.
- Immutability in C# is easily subverted by reflection. There are [edge cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6063546/547365) where it can be subverted even without reflection.

**Immutability in Rust**

```rs
struct Foo {
    bar: Bar,
    lives: u32
}
```

The first thing to note is that the struct definition says nothing of the immutability of its fields. That's because there is no such thing as field-level mutability in rust. Mutability in Rust is defined on the *binding* to a value:

```rs
// Declare an immutable binding to a Foo
let foo = Foo { bar: Bar::new(), lives: 10 };

// Attempting to mutate the value that foo points to is a compile error
foo.lives = 5; // compile error!

foo.bar.baz = 6; // Also a compile error, foo is deeply immutable

// We can redefine the binding to be mutable
let mut foo = foo; // foo is now mutable!

foo.lives = 5; // mutating foo here would be valid
foo.bar.baz = 6; // this is also valid, foo is deeply mutable
```

As you can see, mutability in Rust is simpler and less nuanced than in C#: It's the binding to a value that determines if it's mutable, and it's either deeply mutable or deeply immutable<sup>*</sup>.

**With all that out of the way, let's try to model your problem in Rust.**

First, we'll define a trait with an equivalent `GetNumber()` method:

```rs
trait Bar {
    fn number(&self) -> u32;
}
```

Since `number()` takes an immutable binding to `self`, any type that implements `Bar` will not be able to mutate itself via a call to `number()`:

```rs
struct Foo {
    number: u32,
    oranges: u32
}

impl Bar for Foo {
    fn number(&self) -> u32 {
        self.number += 1; // Compile error. We have an immutable binding to self
        self.number
    }
}
```

As you can see, controlling mutability in Rust is all about controlling how bindings are defined.

Let's introduce a method to our trait that defines a mutable binding to `self` and update our implementation on `Foo`:

```rs
trait Bar {
    fn number(&self) -> u32;
    fn inc_oranges(&mut self);
}

impl Bar for Foo {
    fn number(&self) -> u32 {
        self.number
    }
    
    fn inc_oranges(&mut self) {
        // We have a mutable reference to self. We can mutate any part of self:
        self.oranges += 1;
        self.number += 1; // We can *also* mutate number
    }
}
```

This is where you might start favoring the C# approach: In C#, you can declare `number` as a readonly field while leaving `oranges` to be mutable, but in Rust, if a trait declares a mutable binding to `self`, any part of `self` can be mutated. Fortunately, there is a way around this.

<sup>*</sup>**Interior mutability**

Rust provides a way mutate values that are part of an immutable binding by way of the [cell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/) module. To make a long story short, these types allow for mutation while still accommodating the guarantees afforded by using immutable bindings. It does this by moving what would otherwise be a compile-time (zero-cost) check to a runtime check.

Let's put it all together now:

```rs
struct Foo {
    number: u32,
    orange: Cell<u32>, // allow mutation via an immutable binding
}

trait Bar {
    fn number(&self) -> u32;
    fn inc_oranges(&self); // self is now an immutable binding
}

impl Bar for Foo {
    fn number(&self) -> u32 {
        self.number
    }
    
    fn inc_oranges(&self) {
        
        // We can mutate oranges via cell functions even though self is immutable
        let cur_oranges = self.oranges.get();
        self.oranges.set(cur_oranges + 1);

        self.number += 1; // This would be a compile error
    }
}
```

In summary, we can effectively achieve an equivalent to your C# example by way of:

- Defining immutable bindings to `self` on impls
- Using cell types to allow interior mutability on immutable bindings

With all that being said, it wouldn't be idiomatic or performant to model all your types this way. What's more important is knowing when and where it's appropriate to allow mutation, not micro-managing mutation of specific fields via cell types.

Comment: `let foo = mut foo;` should be `let mut foo = foo;`